# How to insert a Distinct and Order in include?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

i'm doing a project in nodejs (express and angular) and im finding difficulties with this sequielize. I cannot add a distinct (at the beginning of the query, i receive too much copies) and i cannot add an order by for a "include field"

I went through Sequielize documentation ( http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators-aliases ) but without success. I found some answers in here but still no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
    return models.Inspection.findAndCountAll({
        distinct: true,
        attributes: [],
        include: [{model: models.InspectionGroup, attributes:['ID', 'InspectionTypeModel_ID', 'Notes', 'Date'], 
                            required: true, include: [{
                                model: models.InspectionTypeModel, attributes: ['Model'], required: true
                            }]},
                    {model: models.UnitElement, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                        model: models.Span, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                            model: models.StructuralUnit, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                                model: models.Building, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                                    model: models.Direction, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                                        model: models.Road, attributes: [], where: {Dealer_ID: dealerList}, required: true
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }],
    order: [[ { model: models.InspectionGroup }, 'Date', 'DESC']],
    limit: limit,
    offset: offset
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        res.json(results);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        commons.showerror(err, res);
    });
```

This is the sql generated:

```
SELECT [Inspection].[ID], [InspectionGroup].[ID] AS [InspectionGroup.ID], [InspectionGroup].[InspectionTypeModel_ID] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel_ID], 
    [InspectionGroup].[Notes] AS [InspectionGroup.Notes], [InspectionGroup].[Date] AS [InspectionGroup.Date], [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel].[ID] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel.ID], 
    [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel].[Model] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel.Model] 
FROM [Inspection] AS [Inspection] 
INNER JOIN [InspectionGroup] AS [InspectionGroup] ON [Inspection].[InspectionGroup_ID] = [InspectionGroup].[ID] 
INNER JOIN [InspectionTypeModel] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel] ON [InspectionGroup].[InspectionTypeModel_ID] = [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel].[ID] 
INNER JOIN [UnitElement] AS [UnitElement] ON [Inspection].[UnitElement_ID] = [UnitElement].[ID] INNER JOIN [Span] AS [UnitElement.Span] ON [UnitElement].[Span_ID] = [UnitElement.Span].[ID] 
INNER JOIN [StructuralUnit] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit] ON [UnitElement.Span].[StructuralUnit_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit].[ID] INNER JOIN [Building] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building] ON [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit].[Building_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building].[ID] 
INNER JOIN [Direction] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction] ON [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building].[Direction_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction].[ID] INNER JOIN [Road] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction.Road] ON [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction].[Road_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction.Road].[ID] AND [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction.Road].[Dealer_ID] IN (4, 12) 
ORDER BY [InspectionGroup].[Date] DESC ORDER BY [ID] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

And this is the error 
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

I can see that the sequielize generated 2 different order by, but I actually don't know why it generates the "ID order by", considering i specified that the order by should be on InspectionGroup.Date...and the "distinct:true" is totally ignored.

Edit (generated SQL with attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('distinct', Sequelize.col('ID')), 'inspectionId']])
And error: "Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement."

```
SELECT [Inspection].[ID], distinct([ID]) AS [inspectionId], [InspectionGroup].[ID] AS [InspectionGroup.ID], [InspectionGroup].[InspectionTypeModel_ID] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel_ID], 
    [InspectionGroup].[Notes] AS [InspectionGroup.Notes], [InspectionGroup].[Date] AS [InspectionGroup.Date], [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel].[ID] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel.ID], 
    [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel].[Model] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel.Model]
    FROM [Inspection] AS [Inspection] 
    INNER JOIN [InspectionGroup] AS [InspectionGroup] ON [Inspection].        [InspectionGroup_ID] = [InspectionGroup].[ID] 
    INNER JOIN [InspectionTypeModel] AS [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel] ON [InspectionGroup].[InspectionTypeModel_ID] = [InspectionGroup.InspectionTypeModel].[ID] 
    INNER JOIN [UnitElement] AS [UnitElement] ON [Inspection].[UnitElement_ID] = [UnitElement].[ID] INNER JOIN [Span] AS [UnitElement.Span] ON [UnitElement].[Span_ID] = [UnitElement.Span].[ID] 
    INNER JOIN [StructuralUnit] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit] ON [UnitElement.Span].[StructuralUnit_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit].[ID] INNER JOIN [Building] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building] ON [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit].[Building_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building].[ID] 
    INNER JOIN [Direction] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction] ON [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building].[Direction_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction].[ID] 
    INNER JOIN [Road] AS [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction.Road] ON [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction].[Road_ID] = [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction.Road].[ID] AND [UnitElement.Span.StructuralUnit.Building.Direction.Road].[Dealer_ID] IN (4, 12) 
    ORDER BY [Inspection].[Date] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, you should put at least one attribute on the route model to be able to apply distinct on that column. Otherwise, there is no column to apply it.

Let’s try and see if it works

```
distinct: true,
attributes: [´id’]
```

Hope it will help you

[EDIT]

With the following update it should be fine

```
return models.Inspection.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: [[ Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', Sequelize.col('Inspection.ID')), 'Inspection.ID']],
    include: [{model: models.InspectionGroup, attributes:['ID', 'InspectionTypeModel_ID', 'Notes', 'Date'], 
                        required: true, include: [{
                            model: models.InspectionTypeModel, attributes: ['Model'], required: true
                        }]},
                {model: models.UnitElement, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                    model: models.Span, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                        model: models.StructuralUnit, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                            model: models.Building, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                                model: models.Direction, attributes: [], required: true, include: [{
                                    model: models.Road, attributes: [], where: {Dealer_ID: dealerList}, required: true
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }],
order: [[ { model: models.InspectionGroup }, 'Date', 'DESC']],
limit: limit,
offset: offset
})
.then(function (results) {
    res.json(results);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    commons.showerror(err, res);
});
```

Comment: Sorry if I answer this late...and thanks for your reply! Sadly, this doesn't work...the query works good (except the Order By) but still no distinct...it seems sequielize ignore the "distinct: true"

Comment: did you log the query generated ? to see what is in the SELECT statement

Comment: Yes I did...the query generated is the same I put in my original post...with the distinct ignored and the ID selected (apparently sequielize select the ID of the first model by default if you don't select any attribute, so adding attributes: ['ID'] does not make any change)

Comment: Can you try this attributes: [[Sequelize.fn(‘distinct’), Sequelize.col(‘id’), ´inspectionId’]]

Comment: I replaced it in the upper part, right under the "distinct:true" part, replacing attributes: ['ID'], is that correct?

distinct: true,
attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('distinct'), Sequelize.col('ID'), 'ID']],

If so, it gives me error: "identifier.replace is not a function"

Comment: Yeah and you can remove distinct true then

Comment: Sorry I edited my comment just while you're answering, it gives me error "identifier.replace is not a function"

Comment: my bad it is `[Sequelize.fn(‘distinct’, Sequelize.col(‘ID’)), ´inspectionID’]] `

Comment: A distinct is generated, but it duplicates the ID, this is weird:
SELECT [Inspection].[ID], distinct([ID]) AS [inspectionId]

And this is double weird cause I didnt selected 'ID' ([Inspection].[ID] in the query), but just 'ID' with sequelize (but it generates "distinct([ID]) AS [inspectionId]", and I'm not sure it takes the right field, no [Inspection] as prefix)

Comment: if is adding `DISTINCT(id)`  with all the join you should get an error for ambiguous column normally can you past the generated query ?

Comment: what happen when you execute the request in your DB editor ? use logging: console.log to have the rawQuery

Comment: and you can update as `attributes: [[Sequelize.fn(‘distinct’, Sequelize.col(‘Inspection.ID’)), ´inspectionID’]]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend with rawQuery...i'm using the "sequelize_logging":true in my config to see what the sequelize is generating. With your update, it still duplicates the IDs: SELECT [Inspection].[ID], distinct([Inspection].[ID]) AS [inspectionID] ....

Comment: This is weird, the last way is to do a rawQuery with `sequelize.query()` ^^

Comment: I know, but I wanted to avoid that, because I can't simulate a pagination with a "normal" query. Using limit and offset with sequelize in that form helps me to paginate correctly the data, a "normal" query wouldn't let me do that :/

Comment: what do you mean ? you can paginate easily with a raw query as well. What's the probleme ?

Comment: It's hard to explain...I'm not working on a project on my own and they started to build everything with sequelize (kinda weird that they didn't ever use distinct) and all is built up for that. No space for raw query, and I don't want to change everything for a single query....I just saw a thing, I got "sequelize": "^3.24.3", the problem could be resolved with an update?

Comment: Yeah you can try to update the package unless you have some restriction on the project. In my company we using a lot of sequelize and we have our own fork for customization, but depends on the performance that we need we have a mix in part of our code where we using raw queries. You can save a lot of performances.

Comment: Yeah i know...it's the first time I use sequelize, I always user raw queries, that's why I'm kinda lost...but thanks anyway, you're very kind, really thank you!

Comment: It’s a pleasure if you find the answer tell me ;)

Comment: My boss said I could try with raw query but it didn't work...then i realized that the page where I should visualize the result (with a table) accept only data with a total count of the results row. I succed in pagination with raw query, and I think I could be an idiot xD Well what to say, thank you for your help, and I'm sorry about the time I made you lose :/